Accessing Attributes in nested InnerBlocks [Wordpress - Metabox]
I try to send one value from two nested innerBlocks. The blocks are written in php and build with Meta-box.
$insertUrl is retrieve dynamically from php in the bloc parent. I try to send it to the 'core/button' url attributes which is displayed from an innerblock in the child block.
here is the child block :
<?php 
$insertUrl = mb_get_block_field('downloadUrl') ?? '';
var_dump($insertUrl)
?>
 <div class="child-bloc">

      <InnerBlocks
          allowedBlocks="<?= esc_attr( json_encode( [
             'core/heading',
             'core/paragraph',
             'core/buttons',
          ] ) ) ?>"

           template="<?= esc_attr( json_encode( [
                    [ 'core/heading',   [ 'placeholder' => 'Title' ] ],
                    [ 'core/paragraph', [ 'placeholder' => 'paragraph' ] ],
                    [ 'core/button',   [ 'placeholder' => $insertUrl] ],
           ] ) ) ?>"

       />

  </div>

with that field/attribute
 [
    'name' => 'Texte',
    'id'   => 'insertUrl',
    'type' => 'text',
 ]

And in my parent block, i have another innerBlocks who try to send the url to the template.
<div class="parent-block">

    <InnerBlocks
        allowedBlocks="<?= esc_attr( json_encode( [
        'meta-box/encart-informatif',
        ]) ) ?>"
                
         template="<?= esc_attr( json_encode( [
                [ 'meta-box/encart-informatif',
                       [  'innerBlocks', [
                            [ 'core/button',   [ 'placeholder' => '', 'url' => 'INSERTURL'] ],
                        ]],
                    ],
                    ]) ) ?>"
             />
    </div>

But this doesn't work and $insertUrl is often empty...
Is this possible ?
